# Need help with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

so I have created a link and am using jquery and ajax to load a new web page using this link, now is there anyway where I can change some content on this dynamically loaded page?
 For example, the new page has a drop-down list, so can I somehow set the value of this drop-down list.

I tried to using the following in the load function

```
$('#content').load("inq.html #content",function(){
('selectid').val('optionvalue'); 
});
```

The selectid and optionvalue are in the loaded page.
This did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. In your example you forgot the jQuery object and didn't have the correct selector in the callback:

```
$('#content').load("inq.html #content",function(){
    $('#selectid').val('optionvalue'); 
});
```

Comment: Yup this is the solution, I was not putting the value of the option tag, was putting the text enclosed by the option tag. Thanxs for your help.

Answer (score 1):

your url appears to be malformed.  something like "/inq.html#html"

http://api.jquery.com/load/